# How to append to a Pandas Dataframe dependent on the predicted class

Tags: python, pandas

My Pandas DataFrame holds all possible classes of a Machine-Learning problem in the columns, the value assigned to an entry has the meaning of its probability.

Next, I have a Machine-Learning model that gives class predictions for train cases.

Now I want to add a new row for every prediction, where the value in the column assigned to the predicted class gets 1.

How can I append to a Pandas Dataframe dependent on the predicted class in an efficient and elegant way?

This is some minimal sample code that does what I want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

predictions = np.array(['classB', 'classB', 'classC'])
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['classA', 'classB', 'classC'])

print "Data before:" 
print data

for i in range(len(predictions)):
    if predictions[i] == "classA":
        data.loc[i] = [1, 0, 0]
    if predictions[i] == "classB":
        data.loc[i] = [0, 1, 0]
    if predictions[i] == "classC":
        data.loc[i] = [0, 0, 1]

print "Data after:"
print data
```

**Input:**

```
 Empty Dataframe, prediction = ['classB', 'classB', 'classC']
```

**Output:**

```
   classA  classB  classC
0     0.0     1.0     0.0
1     0.0     1.0     0.0
2     0.0     0.0     1.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider using a [pandas.DataFrame.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to get rid of the `for` and `if` construct.

You would create a pandas data frame which maps a class to its probabilities (e.g. 'classA': [1,0,0]). Afterwards merge this mapping with the predicted classes.

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

classes = ['classA', 'classB', 'classC']

predictionProbabilityMapping = pd.DataFrame(index=classes, columns=classes, data=[
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
])

def convertProbabilities(predictions):
    predictionsDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['classification'], data=predictions)
    return pd.merge(predictionsDf, 
                    predictionProbabilityMapping, 
                    left_on='classification', right_index=True)[classes]

predictions = np.array(['classB', 'classB', 'classC'])
print convertProbabilities(predictions)
```

Which yields:

```
       classA  classB  classC
0       0       1       0
1       0       1       0
2       0       0       1
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer!